Bracket matching - Advent of Code 2021 Day 10
The following code solves Advent Of Code 2021 Day 10.
The goal for this time around is evaluating whether a line of brackets
is complete, has a syntax error or is missing some closing brackets.
Examples of valid pairs of brackets
()
[] 
([])
{()()()}
<([{}])>
[<>({}){}[([])<>]]
(((((((((())))))))))

Example of incorrect or corrupted lines
{([(<{}[<>[]}>{[]{[(<()>   # Expected ], but found } instead.
[[<[([]))<([[{}[[()]]]     # Expected ], but found ) instead.
[{[{({}]{}}([{[{{{}}([]    # Expected ), but found ] instead.
[<(<(<(<{}))><([]([]()     # Expected >, but found ) instead.
<{([([[(<>()){}]>(<<{{     # Expected ], but found > instead.

Examples of incomplete lines
[({(<(())[]>[[{[]{<()<>>    # Complete by adding }}]])})].
[(()[<>])]({[<{<<[]>>(      # Complete by adding )}>]}).
(((({<>}<{<{<>}{[]{[]{}     # Complete by adding }}>}>)))).
{<[[]]>}<{[{[{[]{()[[[]     # Complete by adding ]]}}]}]}>.
<{([{{}}[<[[[<>{}]]]>[]]    # Complete by adding ])}>.

Problem:
Advent of code 10 was divided into two problems:

Find the sum of all lines that has a syntax error (corrupted), where every bracket that causes a syntax error is given a particular value.
Find each line that was incomplete, complete the line and find the autocomplete score of the completed portion. For every line in the test data, we were then asked to find the median of the autocomplete scores.

Code
from typing import Final

# Points for each illegal character
points: Final[dict[str, int]] = {
    ')': 3,
    ']': 57,
    '}': 1197,
    '>': 25137
}

# Bracket pairs
pairs: Final[dict[str, int]] = {
    '(': ')',
    '[': ']',
    '{': '}',
    '<': '>'
}

# Values for scoring completion characters
values: Final[dict[str, int]] = {
    ')': 1,
    ']': 2,
    '}': 3,
    '>': 4
}

def syntax_error_score_and_autocomplete_score(lines):
    scores = []
    total_score = 0

    for line in lines:
        stack = []
        corrupted = False
        corrupted_char = None
        for char in line.strip():
            if char in pairs:
                # Opening bracket
                stack.append(char)
            else:
                # Closing bracket
                if not stack:
                    # Extra closing bracket, corrupted
                    corrupted = True
                    corrupted_char = char
                    break
                top = stack.pop()
                if pairs[top] != char:
                    # Mismatched closing bracket, corrupted
                    corrupted = True
                    corrupted_char = char
                    break

        # Ignore corrupted lines
        # If the line is corrupted, add the corresponding points
        if corrupted:
            total_score += points[corrupted_char]
            continue

        # If stack is not empty, we need to complete the line
        if stack:
            completion_string = ""
            while stack:
                opening = stack.pop()
                completion_string += pairs[opening]

            # Calculate score for this completion string
            score = 0
            for ch in completion_string:
                score = score * 5 + values[ch]
            scores.append(score)

    print("part1: (syntax_error_score)", total_score)
    scores.sort()
    # Get the middle score
    print("part2: (autocomplete_score)", scores[len(scores)//2])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("D:\\ExplorerDownload\\input2021_day10.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    syntax_error_score_and_autocomplete_score(lines)


What's an "autocomplete score"?  I've not heard that term before.

Looks good. It is easy to read, with clear identifiers.
extra boolean
This is some nice, idiomatic code.
        corrupted_char = None

Given the type of str | None,
we don't need a bool corrupted flag alongside it.
Testing if the char is None does the same job as seeing if the flag is False.
Fewer state variables means fewer things to keep juggling in your head.
On which topic...
extract helper
We strive to write short functions which can be viewed
in a single screenful, without vertical scrolling.
That for char ... loop performs a nice localized computation
and is a good candidate for packaging up in a helper function.
Pass in a line and a stack, side effect the stack, and get
back a corrupted_char.
odd annotation
We don't tend to often see Final in annotated production code.
pairs: Final[dict[str, int]] = {

Quoting from its documentation:

A final name cannot be re-assigned or overridden in a subclass. ...
There is no runtime checking of these properties.

Consider instead using from types import MappingProxyType
and assign one of those.
Type checkers know all about it, plus its cousins such as frozenset.
Runtime mutation attempts will produce
TypeError: 'mappingproxy' object does not support item assignment
In the simpler scalar case, rather than marking it Final
we typically will upcase such constants, e.g. SECONDS_PER_DAY = 86400.
And yes, linters will call you out if they see you
trying to increment such a quantity.
And do run pyright or mypy over your code after
you've annotated it.
That dict[str, int] copy-pasta mapping makes no sense.
You wanted dict[str, str].
Bad annotations are noticed by type checkers,
but have no effect at runtime.
extra comments
This source code is perhaps a little on the chatty side, but not
overly so, not so much that it worries me.
Do consider deleting the occasional comment if you feel it says
nothing more than what the code already has eloquently stated.
Your descriptive identifiers are a big help in that regard.
This was the only comment item that gave me pause:
            if char in pairs:
                # Opening bracket
                stack.append(char)

It makes me slightly sad, because ideally an identifier
like pairs should be doing the work of explaining that.
Yet I couldn't think of a better name than pairs, sorry.
Maybe def is_opening_bracket(char): is the best way out of this?
median

... we were then asked to find the median of the autocomplete scores.

    print("part2: (autocomplete_score)", scores[len(scores)//2])

I didn't notice anything in your problem statement which promises
there shall be an odd number of scores.
In the even case I would expect a
median
computation to find the mean of the two central figures.
Notice that if there's a bunch of repeated scores this code
might "get lucky", as the mean of two equal numbers is identical
to the value of either one of them.
But with enough test inputs your luck will eventually run out.

In addition to the points raised in the previous answer, here are some
other items to consider.
Naming
User @J_H
makes an astute point that you only need to retain one of these variables:
corrupted
corrupted_char

However,if you do decide to keep both, I recommend renaming corrupted
as is_corrupted.  Adding the is_ prefix is a common practice for
booleans, and it would more clearly distinguish the 2 variables by name.
Comments
My first impression while reading through the code was that the
function had well-placed comments that helped me understand what was
going on.
Magic number
It is not obvious to me what the significance of the 5 is in
the following line:
            score = score * 5 + values[ch]

Perhaps a comment would help to clarify.
Which leads us to ...
Documentation
I understand that the focus for programming challenges is functionality,
and the last thing your are thinking about is documentation, but adding some
simple docstrings would help to understand the purpose of the code.

I agree that 5 is inscrutable. I take it to be "one more than max(values.values())". @138Aspen, would you please edit the question to at least include a Part Two link? And ideally add one or more sentences so the CodeReview question makes sense on its own, even if the AoC problem description page were to go 404.

@J_H please don't ask to copy&paste AOC problem texts here, it's forbidden by AOC rules. And there's no part 2 link - part 2 opens for signed in users who solved part 1 of that day, and there's a reason for such treatment. So OP can only rephrase the question in their own words

@STerliakov, I was only trying to minimize the OP's effort. @138Aspen, would you please take another stab at rephrasing the Part Two question in your own words? The CodeReview question as written does not offer sufficient detail for a reviewer to adequately understand the problem assignment to properly review the code. In particular the 5 is inscrutable and the AoC site is perhaps not using the word "median" in the way that most high school math teachers would use it. Maybe medoid was intended?

I know the problem stmt, median calculation here is correct - the problem promised there will always be an odd number of malformed lines. (But yes, the question should be edited to clarify this and scoring rules)

Other answers say the code is easy to read, and I'm in no position to contradict that, as readability is always subjective. But to me, this code is not easy to read. It's just one big function with very deeply nested loops and conditionals, even with breaks and continues, and I have to read and understand all of it to get a sense of what's going on. I can only understand it because I happen to know the requirements (the AoC question).
So in my opinion, the first improvement to make is to divide this code into smaller bits that make sense on their own, and extract them into their own functions or even files.
Speaking of dividing, there are two very independent concerns in this solution. There is parsing a line, and there is computing some score based on the results. They're conceptually separate issues, but in this code they're all mixed up.
Another hint that the code is not readable is that it needs so many comments. Right now the comments make sense of it, but they wouldn't be necessary if the code were self-explanatory. For example, these comments:
# Points for each illegal character
points: Final[dict[str, int]] 
...
# Values for scoring completion characters
values: Final[dict[str, int]]

Are not necessary if you just give the variables clearer names:
points_for_illegal_chars: Final[dict[str, int]] 
points_for_completion_chars: Final[dict[str, int]]

Then this comment
# Calculate score for this completion string

Is not necessary if you have a function about calculating something
And this comment
# Get the middle score
print("part2: (autocomplete_score)", scores[len(scores)//2])

Is not necessary if you define a median function
print("part2: (autocomplete_score)", median(scores))

...

def median(values):
    return sorted(values)[len(values) // 2

Here's the code I ended with after refactoring yours. The main difference is that I've tried to keep the parsing logic separate from the scoring logic. To me, that's non-negotiable as otherwise there's no way you could write tests for the parsing bit. There are some other decisions that are way more subjective, such as the use of exceptions for control flow and parsing each line twice, and whether the parsing logic shouldn't be all just kept in just one function.
# parsing.py

from typing import Final

_bracket_pairs: Final[dict[str, int]] = {
    '(': ')',
    '[': ']',
    '{': '}',
    '<': '>'
}


def parse_line(line):
    _ParseAlgorithm().run(line)


class _ParseAlgorithm:

    def run(self, line):

        self._initialize()

        for char in line.strip():
            if self._is_valid_opener(char):
                self._open_group(char)
            elif self._is_valid_closer(char):
                self._close_group()
            else:
                raise UnexpectedCharException(char)

        if self._expected_closers:
            raise IncompleteLineException(self._expected_closers)

    def _initialize(self):
        self._expected_closers = []

    def _is_valid_opener(self, char):
        return char in _bracket_pairs.keys()

    def _is_valid_closer(self, char):
        return self._expected_closers and self._expected_closers[0] == char

    def _open_group(self, char):
        self._expected_closers.insert(0, _bracket_pairs[char])

    def _close_group(self):
        self._expected_closers.pop(0)


class UnexpectedCharException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, unexpected_char):
        self.unexpected_char = unexpected_char


class IncompleteLineException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, missing_string):
        self.missing_string = missing_string

# scoring.py

from typing import Final

import parsing

_corruption_points: Final[dict[str, int]] = {
    ')': 3,
    ']': 57,
    '}': 1197,
    '>': 25137
}

_autocomplete_points: Final[dict[str, int]] = {
    ')': 1,
    ']': 2,
    '}': 3,
    '>': 4
}


def compute_corruption_score(lines):
    result = 0
    for line in lines:
        try:
            parsing.parse_line(line)
        except parsing.UnexpectedCharException as e:
            result += _corruption_points[e.unexpected_char]
        except parsing.IncompleteLineException:
            pass
    return result


def compute_autocomplete_score(lines):
    autocomplete_scores = []
    for line in lines:
        try:
            parsing.parse_line(line)
        except parsing.UnexpectedCharException:
            pass
        except parsing.IncompleteLineException as e:
            autocomplete_scores.append(_autocomplete_score_single_line(e.missing_string))

    return _median(autocomplete_scores)


def _autocomplete_score_single_line(missing_string):
    result = 0
    for ch in missing_string:
        result *= 5
        result += _autocomplete_points[ch]
    return result


def _median(values):
    return sorted(values)[len(values) // 2]

# main.py

import scoring

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("./input2021_day10.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    print("part1: (syntax_error_score)", scoring.compute_corruption_score(lines))
    print("part2: (autocomplete_score)", scoring.compute_autocomplete_score(lines))

